Can't Enter Text in to text box in html
I have input fields I created with HTML and when I run the page I cannot enter data in to the text boxes. I tried disabled=false but it did not work. The input fields I'm having problems with are email and password. I also placed the input fields in to a form. I also placed the input text boxes inside a div. Will this affect the program? Please help. Thanks.


window.addEventListener("load", function () { document.getElementById("formb").style.display = "none" });
const register = document.getElementById("register");
const login = document.getElementById("forma")
register.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("forma").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("formb").style.display = "block";

});


const account = document.getElementById("account");
account.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("formb").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("forma").style.display = "block";
});

const sublogin = document.getElementById("sublogin");
sublogin.addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert("Form submitted")
})

const subregister = document.getElementById("subregister");
subregister.addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert("Form submitted")
})

document.getElementById("forma").setAttribute("disabled", false);
#menu,
#footer-menu {


    text-align: center;

}



nav {

    margin: auto;

    line-height: 60px;
}

header {
    margin: -8px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}



a {
    margin: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: black;
}


footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

div#center {
    text-align: center;

}


input {
    margin: .1rem;

}

#label {
    position: relative;
    top: 73px;
    left: 35%;
           }

div#label {
    margin-top: .7rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: .9rem;
    font-size: 18px;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}



#register {
    display: inline;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#logbtn {
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: green;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 5px;
    left: 51%;
    color: white;
}

input[type=submit] {
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: green;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 5px;
    left: 51%;
    color: white;
}

#account {
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
   
</head>

<body>
    <header><img src="logo.jpg" style="height: 75px; width: 75px;" id="logo">

        <div id="menu">
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html">Home|</a>
                <a href="math-facts.html">Games|</a>
                <a href="about.html">About|</a>
                <a href="login.html">Login</a>


            </nav>
        </div>

    </header>
    <form id="forma">
        <h2 id="h2">Log in</h2>
        <div id="label">
            <div>Email:</div>
            <div>Password:</div>

            <p id="register">Need an account? Register</p>

        </div>
        <!-- <form id="forma"> -->
        <div id="center">

            <!-- <label for="email">Email:</label> -->
            <input name="email" type="email" id="email"><br>

            <!-- <label for="password">Password:</label> -->
            <input type="password" id="password"><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Log in" id="sublogin"><br>
        </div>
    </form>

    <form id="formb">
        <h2 id="h2">Register</h2>
        <div id="label">
            <div>Email:</div>
            <div>Password:</div>
            <div>Repeat Password:</div>



        </div>



        <div id="center">

            <!-- <label for="email">Email:</label> -->
            <input name="email" type="email" id="email"><br>

            <!-- <label for="password">Password:</label> -->
            <input type="password" id="password"><br>

            <!-- <label for="password2">Repeat Password:</label> -->
            <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2"><br>



            <input type="checkbox" id="over"><label for="over">I am over 13 and like playing games.</label><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Register" id="subregister"><br>
        </div>
        <p id="account">Have an account? Log in</p>
    </form>





    <footer>
        <hr>
        <div id="footer-menu">
            <nav>
                <a href="contact-us.html"><img src="icon-contact-us.png"></a>
                <a href="https://instagram.com"><img src="icon-instagram.png"></a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com"><img src="icon-twitter.png"></a>
                <a href="https://facebook.com"><img src="icon-facebook.png"></a>


            </nav>
        </div>
    </footer>
    

    
    
    
    
    </body>
    
    </html>




The problem is with the #label div that is overlapping your inputs. Don't use a div for adding label just use label HTML element with input

How would I center both the label and input box? I want to line up the labels from the left and line up the input boxes. Thanks.

Try to remove position absolute for your input and relative for label div. Wrap the new label and correponding input in a div. Style this div using display flex to make them as you want

You have placed the labels above the inputs. Here's a quick fix:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #menu,
        #footer-menu {

            
            text-align: center;
            
        }

        

        nav {

            margin: auto;

            line-height: 60px;
        }

        header {
            margin: -8px;
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            height: 75px;
            background-color: antiquewhite;
        }

        

        a {
            margin: auto;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 24px;
            color: black;
        }


        footer {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 75px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: antiquewhite;
        }

        div#center {
            text-align: center;
           
        }


        input {
            margin: .1rem;
           
        }

        #label {
            position: relative;
            top: 73px;
            left: 0%;
            width: 30%;
                   }

        div#label {
            margin-top: .7rem;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding-top: .9rem;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        h2 {
            text-align: center;
        }

     

        #register {
            display: inline;
            color: blue;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        #logbtn {
            position: absolute;
            width: 75px;
            height: 25px;
            background-color: green;
            display: inline;
            border-radius: 5px;
            left: 51%;
            color: white;
        }

        input[type=submit] {
            position: absolute;
            width: 75px;
            height: 25px;
            background-color: green;
            display: inline;
            border-radius: 5px;
            left: 51%;
            color: white;
        }

        #account {
            text-align: center;
            color: blue;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        #logo {
            float: left;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <header><img src="logo.jpg" style="height: 75px; width: 75px;" id="logo">

        <div id="menu">
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html">Home|</a>
                <a href="math-facts.html">Games|</a>
                <a href="about.html">About|</a>
                <a href="login.html">Login</a>


            </nav>
        </div>

    </header>
    <form id="forma">
        <h2 id="h2">Log in</h2>
        <div id="label">
            <div>Email:</div>
            <div>Password:</div>

            <p id="register">Need an account? Register</p>

        </div>
        <!-- <form id="forma"> -->
        <div id="center">

            <!-- <label for="email">Email:</label> -->
            <input name="email" type="email" id="email"><br>

            <!-- <label for="password">Password:</label> -->
            <input type="password" id="password"><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Log in" id="sublogin"><br>
        </div>
    </form>

    <form id="formb">
        <h2 id="h2">Register</h2>
        <div id="label">
            <div>Email:</div>
            <div>Password:</div>
            <div>Repeat Password:</div>



        </div>



        <div id="center">

            <!-- <label for="email">Email:</label> -->
            <input name="email" type="email" id="email"><br>

            <!-- <label for="password">Password:</label> -->
            <input type="password" id="password"><br>

            <!-- <label for="password2">Repeat Password:</label> -->
            <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2"><br>



            <input type="checkbox" id="over"><label for="over">I am over 13 and like playing games.</label><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Register" id="subregister"><br>
        </div>
        <p id="account">Have an account? Log in</p>
    </form>





    <footer>
        <hr>
        <div id="footer-menu">
            <nav>
                <a href="contact-us.html"><img src="icon-contact-us.png"></a>
                <a href="https://instagram.com"><img src="icon-instagram.png"></a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com"><img src="icon-twitter.png"></a>
                <a href="https://facebook.com"><img src="icon-facebook.png"></a>


            </nav>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script>

        window.addEventListener("load", function () { document.getElementById("formb").style.display = "none" });
        const register = document.getElementById("register");
        const login = document.getElementById("forma")
        register.addEventListener("click", function () {
            document.getElementById("forma").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("formb").style.display = "block";

        });


        const account = document.getElementById("account");
        account.addEventListener("click", function () {
            document.getElementById("formb").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("forma").style.display = "block";
        });

        const sublogin = document.getElementById("sublogin");
        sublogin.addEventListener("click", function () {
            alert("Form submitted")
        })

        const subregister = document.getElementById("subregister");
        subregister.addEventListener("click", function () {
            alert("Form submitted")
        })

        document.getElementById("forma").setAttribute("disabled", false);
          
    </script>




</body>

</html>



This is what I changed:
            #label {
                position: relative;
                top: 73px;
                left: 0%;
                width: 30%;
            }

I have changed left to move it to the leftmost position and decreased widthto 30%. You can of course adjust this further, but this should be a good start.

Your text inputs appear to be completely covered by their labels, that's why you cannot click and edit values. You can see it by using Chrome developer tools.

One way to resolve this is to remove the div with id="label" and uncomment the labels inside the form.
